# CPU Barrier in Large Combination

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying a script that can calculate all 8-digit probabilities that occur with [a-z] [A-Z] [0-9].

Even if my processor is very powerful, it will take weeks to realize all the possibilities as it uses only one core. How can I do this the fastest?

```
import sys
import os

chrList = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

def doCombination(charset, prefix, num):
    if num == 0:      
        print(prefix)
        return
    for letter in (charset):
        hRet = doCombination(charset, prefix + letter, num - 1)

doCombination(chrList, "", 8)
```

Comment: Perhaps this may help you consider if you really want to do this: [relevant Arthur C Clarke story](https://urbigenous.net/library/nine_billion_names_of_god.html).

Comment: @davidbak "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python" you understood me very well :) but python was developed exactly 40 years ago! don't tell me there's no way to do this fast. If you think I will perform on a server with a 56-core processor, the rest is just a good script

Comment: You already have a function for that as [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product): `product(chrList, repeat=8)`

Comment: itertools.product this didn't work very well for me. does not calculate all the possibilities. (Sequential)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips:

- Do not print your output.
- Make your code such that you can restart it half way.
- Save where you are at a regular interval (so that when it crashes you can restart).
- Consider not using Python but something like C or GPU acceleration.

Comment: Just starting from the beginning and the end, the trial time can be cut in half. or trying to mix chrList as 62 threads in total.
1th => a, b, c .....
2th => b, c, a .....
3th => c, d, e .....
when all is complete, all possibilities will be revealed.